# TypeError: PrimeFaces.extend is not a function

Tags: javascript, jsf, jsf-2, primefaces

I'm trying to use PrimeFaces 3.5 with JSF 2.2. When I try to create `p:layout` and `p:layoutUnit`, I get the following error.

```
 Timestamp: 03-06-2013 17:53:42
 Error: TypeError: PrimeFaces.extend is not a function
 Source File: http://localhost:8080/jsfproject2/faces/js/layout.js
 Line: 4390
```

I have included Primefaces3.5.jar and I'm using JQuery 1.6. However,if I use the latest stable version of Jquery (2.02),I get the below error.

```
  Timestamp: 03-06-2013 17:58:53
  Error: TypeError: $.browser is undefined
  Source File: http://localhost:8080/jsfproject2/faces/js/layout.js
  Line: 53
```

I'm not sure if I'm missing anything. Below the javascript files I'm using

```
    <script src="../js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script src="../js/jquery-2.0.2.js"></script>
<script src="../js/watermark.js"></script>
<script src="../js/layout.js"></script>
<script src="../js/core.js"></script>
```

How is this caused and how can I solve it?

Answer (score 0):

Looks like jQuery conflicts... don't include additional jQuery files... Primefaces already got jQuery *under the hood*...

So just remove your own jQuery file...